# Differentiability of an (improper) integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, improper-integrals, uniform-continuity

> let $f: \mathbb{R}^{m+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, define $h_x(y) = f(x,y)$ and suppose $h$ is absolutely integrable in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Define
>   $$F(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} h_x(y)dy$$
>   Further suppose that there exists an absolutely integrable function $g:\mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
>   $$|D_1 f(x,y)| \le g(y)$$
>   for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$. Show that $F$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$

I keep running into circular arguments when trying to prove this and would like some help.

---

It can be shown that $D_1 f(x,y)$ is absolutely integrable over $\mathbb{R}^m$ for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists an approximating sequence $A_n$ (compact/contented sets) to $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N_1$ implies:

$$\left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R^m}} D_1 f(x,y)dy - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)dy \right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$$

$A_n$ is compact/contented, so $D_1f(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous on $A_n$, and so $\exists \eta > 0$ such that $\delta < \eta$ implies
$$|D_1 f(x,y) - D_1 f(x + \delta,y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 v(A_n)}$$

Let $\delta < \eta$. By MVT $\exists \tau$ on the line connecting $(x,y)$ to $(x + \delta,y)$ such that:

$$h_{x+\delta}(y)-h_x(y) = D_1 f(\tau,y) \delta$$
Hence,
$$\frac{F(x + \delta)-F(x)}{\delta} \stackrel{?}{=} \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy$$

Furthermore, $\exists N_2$ such that $n > N_2$ implies:
$$\left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R^m}} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy \right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$$

Let $N = \max \{N_1, N_1 \}$ and $n > N$:

$$\left\lvert \frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta} - \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} D_1 f(x,y)dy \right\rvert <
\left\lvert \frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta} - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)dy \right\rvert + \frac{\epsilon}{4}$$
$$\le \left\lvert \frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta} - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy \right\rvert + \left\lvert \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)dy - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy \right\rvert + \frac{\epsilon}4$$
$$= \left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} D_1f(\tau,y)dy - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy \right\rvert + \left\lvert \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)dy - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy \right\rvert + \frac{\epsilon}4$$
$$\le \left\lvert \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)dy - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau,y)dy \right\rvert + \frac{\epsilon}2$$
$$\le \int_{A_n} |D_1 f(x,y) - D_1 f(\tau, y)| dy + \frac{\epsilon}2$$

$|D_1 f(x,y) - D_1 f(\tau, y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 v(A_n)}$, but this $A_n$ may not be what we are currently integrating over, so this does nothing for us. I also can't change the location of the uniform continuity statement, because $\tau$ depends on $\delta$ which depends on $\eta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can salvage your approach and prove as you intended.

First, you are correct that for sufficiently large $n > N_1$ we find

$$\tag{1}\left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R^m}} D_1 f(x,y)\,dy - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)\,dy \right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{4},
$$

but we can make a stronger statement that this is true for all and not just fixed $x$.  This follows because $|D_1f(x,y)| \leqslant g(y)$ and the convergence $\int_{A_n} \to \int _\mathbb{R^m}$ is uniform by the Weierstrass test.

Define  $F_n(x) = \int_{A_n} f(x,y)\,dy $ and let $n > N_1$ be fixed.

Similar to your attempt, we can apply the triangle inequality and (1) to obtain

$$\tag{2}\left\lvert \frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta} - \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} D_1 f(x,y)\,dy \right\rvert \\ \leqslant \left\lvert \frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta} - \frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta}\right\rvert+
\left\lvert \frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta} - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)\,dy \right\rvert + \frac{\epsilon}{4}
$$

We can use your argument based on the mean value theorem to show that for some $\tau_y$ between $x$ and $x + \delta$ we have

$$\frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta} = \int_{A_n} D_1 f(\tau_y,y)\,dy, $$

and

$$\left\lvert \frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta} - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)\,dy \right\rvert  \leqslant \int_{A_n} |D_1 f(\tau_y,y) - D_1f(x,y)|\,dy  .$$

Using uniform continuity of $D_1f$ on the compact set $A_n$, there exists $\eta > 0$ such that when $\delta < \eta$ we have $|D_1f(\tau_y,y) - D_1f(x,y)| < \epsilon/(4v(A_n)) $ and

$$\left\lvert \frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta} - \int_{A_n} D_1 f(x,y)\,dy\right\rvert   < \frac{\epsilon}{4}.$$

It just remains to show that for sufficiently large $n$, the first term on the RHS of (2) is smaller than $\epsilon/2$.

For $m > n$ we apply the mean value theorem to find $z$ between $x$ and $x + \delta$ such that

$$\left|\frac{F_m(x+\delta)-F_m(x)}{\delta} - \frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta}\right| = \left|\int_{A_m} D_1f(z,y) \, dy - \int_{A_n} D_1f(z,y) \, dy \right| $$

By uniform convergence of $\int_{A_n}$, there exists $N_2$ such that for all $m > n > N_2$ we have

$$\left|\frac{F_m(x+\delta)-F_m(x)}{\delta} - \frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta}\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Taking the limit of both sides, as $m \to \infty$ we get

$$\left|\frac{F_(x+\delta)-F_(x)}{\delta} - \frac{F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x)}{\delta}\right| \leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Therefore, we can find $\eta>0$ such that if $\delta < \eta$ and we have

$$\left\lvert \frac{F(x+\delta)-F(x)}{\delta} - \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} D_1 f(x,y)\,dy \right\rvert < \epsilon.$$

Note that $\eta$ may depend of the fixed $n > \max(N_1,N_2)$ used in the estimate, but this is enough to reach the conclusion that $F$ is differentiable with $F'(x) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}D_1f(x,y) \, dy.$

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can't we directly say that $F_n'(x) = \int_{A_n} D_1f(x,y)dy$? Since $A_n$ is compact and $(f(x+\delta,y)-f(x,y))/\delta \to D_1f(x,y)$ as $\delta \to 0$, I think we are able to commute the limit with the integral. Otherwise, I'm confused about how you're choosing $\tau$. Or rather, why $\tau$ wouldn't depend on $y$.

Comment: Yes for compact $A_n$ and $f \in C^1$ we can switch the integral and derivative.  I'm just proving it.  I edited above to clarify the part about $\tau$.  It does depend on $y$ but by uniform continuity we get $|D_1f(\tau_y,y) - D_1f(x,y)| < \epsilon/(4v(A_n)$ since $|\tau_y - x| \leqslant \delta < \eta$.

Comment: I just used $\tau$ and showed these steps because you started to.  I would be happy to just make the direct statement.

Comment: In general, applying the mean value theorem we get $g(x+ \delta,y) - g(x,y) = D_xg(\xi,y) \delta$. The intermediate point $\xi$ could be different for different fixed $y$.  In the end we don't need to worry about this as I showed.

Comment: I had to study your answer for a little bit, but it just clicked for me!

1) $F_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

2) $F_n'(x) = \int_{A_n} D_1f(x,y)dy$. 

3) We can approximate $\int_{\mathbb{R^m}}D_1 f(x,y)dy$ by the same integral over a compact set.

These three facts allow us to bound everything after the triangle inequality independently. Appropriately choosing $n$ and $\delta$, so that all three occur simultaneously, gives us the result. Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x\in \mathbb R,$ and fix a real sequence $h_n \to 0$ through nonzero values. Define

$$ d_n(y) = \frac{f(x+h_n,y)-f(x,y)}{h_n}.$$

Then $d_n(y) \to D_1f(x,y)$ for every $y\in \mathbb R^m.$

By the mean value theorem, for each $y\in \mathbb R^m,$ there exists $c(y,n)$ between $x$ and $x+h_n$ such that

$$d_n(y) = D_1 f(c(y,n),y).$$

From our hypothesis on $D_1f,$ it follows that $|d_n(y)| \le g(y)\in L^1(\mathbb R^m).$ Thus by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\tag 1 \int_{\mathbb R^m} d_n(y)\, dy \to \int_{\mathbb R^m} D_1f(x,y)\, dy.$$

Now $(F(x+h_n) - F(x))/h_n$ equals the left side of $(1),$ so $(F(x+h_n) - F(x))/h_n$ $\to \int_{\mathbb R^m} D_1f(x,y)\, dy.$ Because $h_n$ was an arbitrary sequence $\to 0,$ we have  $F'(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^m} D_1f(x,y)\, dy.$ Finally, since $x$ was an arbitrary real number, we have $F$ differentiable on $\mathbb R$ as desired.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the dominated convergence theorem, but thank you for the response! This certainly looks like a concise way to answer the problem, a lot more than what I am doing.